# Touch.enable not working in CreateJS through Animate CC

Tags: javascript, touch, createjs, easeljs, animate-cc

I've created an html5 canvas file in Animate CC and I can't seem to get it to respond to touches when run on a touch screen device. I've created a stripped down file to demonstrate the issue.

Every other post I've found online has been resolved with **createjs.Touch.enable(stage)**, however, this doesn't enable touch for me (and it returns false). I've also included adding a **touchstart** event listener but this doesn't help either.

I've also attempted [this](https://community.adobe.com/t5/animate/animate-cc-and-touch-issue-on-iphone/m-p/8712650?page=1) to no effect.

To debug in the console I'm using chrome in device emulation mode. In Animate CC, *centre stage* and *make responsive* are both turned off in the publish settings.

**Results from the example code below:**

- Enabling touch returns false (So this is likely the issue)
- pressing the mouse button returns "mouse down" and shifts ball.
- pressing a touch does nothing
- releasing the touch returns "mouse down" and shifts ball.

**Any idea where I'm going wrong?**
Animate CC is completely up to date and createJS is v1.0.0

Expected behaviour is that the touchstart or mousedown handler is fired when the touch starts just like when using a mouse.

```
console.log("Enable touch: "+createjs.Touch.enable(stage) );  // returns false

ball = this.ball_mc;

// mouse mouse event
ball.on("mousedown", function(event) {
    console.log("mouse down");
    ball.x += 10;
});

// finger down event
ball.addEventListener("touchstart", function mouseDownHandler(e) {
    console.log("finger down");
    ball.x += 10;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an update and answer.
My code above is correct and the issue seen isn't actually an issue.

While I did my initial test on a touch device, I hadn't since, and had assumed that Chrome dev tools touch device emulator was accurate. Turns out it's not!
Chrome dev tools doesn't send a mouse down event on touch and thus doesn't accurately emulate a touch device.

The code above, therefore works fine, but needs to be run directly on a touch device.